# Nginx 404 File not found error for django static files

Tags: nginx, django-staticfiles

I'm getting below error while trying to access static files files, though I'm trying to accessa `static/js/main.js` file, `nginx` is looking for `static/js/main.js/index.html`.. below is the error for the same.

> 2016/01/20 03:31:01 [error] 2410#0: *1
>   "/home/ubuntu/vnv/near/near/static/js/main.js/index.html" is not
>   found (20: Not a directory), client: 162.111.50.122, server: my.domain.com, request: "GET /static/js/main.js/ HTTP/1.1", host: "my.domain.com"

Below is my server block..

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.com;

    # location ~ ^/(static/.*) {
    location ~ /static {
        root /home/ubuntu/vnv/near/near; # near consist of static directory
    }

    location ~ / {
        proxy_headers_hash_max_size 51200;
        proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 6400;
        proxy_pass http://near_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Also it is appending `/` at the end of the URI, what could be the issue here?

Note: I've gone through most of the answers related to this, but I coudn't find proper solution for this situation.

Comment: It would help better if you include your html code or wherever you try to access the file

Comment: @AlexJolig I'm just trying to access the static file directly from the client, but problem here is if I enable `autoindex` then it is getting me the `static` directory only. for remaining files inside static directory it is giving me `404`. BTW these static files are part f my `django` project

Comment: Of course `/home/ubuntu/vnv/near/near/static/js/main.js` exists?

Answer (score 1):

If the request URI ends in a `/`, `nginx` will treat it as a directory and apply the indexing rules. Unless overridden, `nginx` looks for an `index.html` file.

From the error message we see that the GET request was for `/static/js/main.js/`. So the question is *who* appended the `/` to the request URI?

If you now look into the access log, you will see a line containing `GET /static/js/main.js/ HTTP/1.1 404` which lists the HTTP response code.

If the line above contains `GET /static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1 3xx` then `nginx` added the extra `/`. If there is no such line, then the client asked for the wrong URL and you need to be looking for the solution to the problem elsewhere.

Unrelated to your question: Why are you using *regular expression* `location` blocks when *prefix* `location` blocks seem more appropriate?

You should probably be using:

```
location /static { ... }
location / { ... }
```

Your existing configuration is inefficient and matches URIs with `/static` embedded anywhere within the string, such as: `/something/static.php`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for `location` syntax and the processing rules.